# Is "MyType+MyProtocol.kt" extension file name acceptably in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Swift codestyle manual we can read:

> A file containing a single extension to a type MyType that adds
>   conformance to a protocol MyProtocol is named MyType+MyProtocol.swift.

It looks like a good idea to organize small helper functions. Is it applicable for Kotlin? May I name my extension file like a MyType+MyProtocol.kt or this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin's coding conventions on [source code organization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-code-organization) state that:

> In particular, when defining extension functions for a class which are relevant for all clients of this class, put them in the **same file where the class itself is defined**. When defining extension functions that make sense only for a specific client, put them next to the code of that client.

Comment: What about case when we are create extension for built-in class and some protocol? For example, `ByteArray+FTP`?

Comment: @BArtWell The two most common practices I've seen for that case is to append Ext or Extensions to the file name, for example ByteArrayExt, or pluralizing the name (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names) and an example at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt.